# Check for duplicate rows querying only a substring of the data

Tags: php, mysql

I have duplicate images saved in *different directories*.  Because every image location is stored in the database I want to remove duplicate rows of data.  I can use this query to look for duplicate image locations in the *same directory*:

```
SELECT *
FROM page_additional_images
GROUP BY image_loc
HAVING COUNT(image_loc) > 1
```

But, it won't work for images in *different directories* e.g. `cars` & `cars4`.

```
/images/**cars**/hispano-suiza-k6-pictures-and-wallpapers/hispano-suiza-k6.jpg
/images/**cars4**/hispano-suiza-k6-pictures-and-wallpapers/hispano-suiza-k6.jpg
```

How can I take the query above and look for duplicates ignoring everything before the last "`/`"?

I want to explode each row by "/" and only query the last element in each array.

Comment: You need to provide schema information. What are your column names and a sample row of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, the closest you can get to PHP style explode in MySQL is with
SUBSTRING_INDEX (delim='/', with a negative count argument, for example -1 to get only the filename):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score -2):

You can give each entry a Unique id and mysql can tell automatically if a duplicate entry has been made and will prevent it from being queried into the database.  Look up UNIQUE INDEX in the mysql manual

Comment: But, /images/cars4 & /images/cars wouldn't be considered the same.  I want to explode each row by "/" and only query the last element in each array.

Comment: This does not address the question.